# Aggregate values by interval range given by parameter

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a table containing an amount column and an index column.
I wish to build a single query, which sums up the amount for the given interval ranges for every resulting interval from given start index to end index - i.e. the 'interval range' slices the data according index column. For these groups, sum over amount is built.
Is this possible and how?

```
SELECT sum(amount) from mytable
WHERE index between <startindex> and <endindex>
GROUP BY ...
```

Example:

```
amount | index
55        1
88        5
45        6
86        7
87        10
88        11
57        16
58        17
59        20
60        21
```

A query with interval range 5, start index 5 and endindex 14 should result in two return values:

```
  88+45+86 => 219
  87+88    => 175
```

A query with interval range 4, start index 0 and endindex 15 should result in four return values:

```
  55       => 55
  88+45+86 => 219
  87+88    => 175
  --       => 0
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE T(amount INT, index INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(55, 1),(88, 5),(45, 6),(86, 7),(87, 10),
(88, 11),(57, 16),(58, 17),(59, 20),(60, 21);
```

You can take advantage of Postgres function [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-srf.html).

```
generate_series(start, stop, step)
```

> Generate a series of values, from start to stop with a step size of step

The example below uses a series from 0 to 14 with an interval of 4.

```
SELECT generate_series(0, 14, 4) Serie;

| serie |
| ----: |
|     0 |
|     4 |
|     8 |
|    12 |


WITH CTS AS
(
    SELECT generate_series(0, 14, 4) Serie
)
SELECT    COALESCE(SUM(T.amount),0) AS amount, CTS.Serie
FROM      CTS
LEFT JOIN T
ON        T.index >= CTS.Serie 
AND       T.index <  CTS.Serie + 4
GROUP BY  CTS.Serie
ORDER BY  CTS.Serie;

amount | serie
-----: | ----:
    55 |     0
   219 |     4
   175 |     8
     0 |    12
```

You can use a user defined function that allows you to use parameters

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GroupIntervals(low int, high int, step int)
> RETURNS TABLE (amount int, interv int) AS
> $$
> BEGIN
>     RETURN QUERY
>     WITH CTS AS
>     (
>         SELECT generate_series(low, high, step) Serie
>     )
>     SELECT    COALESCE(SUM(T.amount),0)::int AS amount, CTS.Serie as interv
>     FROM      CTS
>     LEFT JOIN T
>     ON        T.index >= CTS.Serie 
>     AND       T.index <  CTS.Serie + step
>     GROUP BY  CTS.Serie
>     ORDER BY  CTS.Serie;
> END;    
> $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM GroupIntervals(0, 14, 4);
> ```
>
> ```
> amount | interv
> -----: | -----:
>     55 |      0
>    219 |      4
>    175 |      8
>      0 |     12
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM GroupIntervals(5, 14, 5);
> ```
>
> ```
> amount | interv
> -----: | -----:
>    219 |      5
>    175 |     10
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=25ec334c5d4d1363ed406cedda1fc782)*

**Update**

As [Evan Carrol](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2639/evan-carroll) has pointed out on him comments you can avoid use CTE and change function language from plpgsql to plain SQL.

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GroupIntervals(low int, high int, step int)
> RETURNS TABLE (amount int, interv int)
> AS $$
>     SELECT    COALESCE(SUM(T.amount),0)::int AS amount, CTS.Serie as interv
>     FROM      generate_series(low, high, step) AS CTS(Serie)
>     LEFT JOIN T
>     ON        index >= CTS.Serie 
>     AND       index <  CTS.Serie + step
>     GROUP BY  CTS.Serie
>     ORDER BY  CTS.Serie;
> $$ LANGUAGE sql;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM GroupIntervals(0, 14, 4);
> ```
>
> ```
> amount | interv
> -----: | -----:
>     55 |      0
>    219 |      4
>    175 |      8
>      0 |     12
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM GroupIntervals(5, 14, 5);
> ```
>
> ```
> amount | interv
> -----: | -----:
>    219 |      5
>    175 |     10
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b559d1233ec66076e40c5aa9505fd727)*

Comment: Incredible answer, thank you for your work!

Comment: I'm glad to help

Comment: @McNets Good answer, but a couple minor points: I wouldn't wrap the `GENERATE_SERIES` in a CTE, and I wouldn't use plpgsql for this. This is just regular `SQL`.

Comment: @McNets http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b559d1233ec66076e40c5aa9505fd727 (feel free to incorporate that into the answer)

Comment: In the updated answer/fiddle: Where comes CTS from? It would be great, if you could explain that. Thank you!!

Comment: It's the alias of generate_series().